# Batch file to search in txt and remove unwanted lines

Tags: batch-file

**I need a batch file to search in the print route:**

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric

      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.0.0.254        10.0.0.31    276
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.10.10.1     10.10.10.134     25
     10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0       10.0.0.254        10.0.0.31     21
     10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link         10.0.0.31    276
    10.0.0.31  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.0.31    276
```

And return  everything  except the the "on-link" lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a script for this.  This is a one liner.

```
route print -4 | find /v /i "on-link"
```